# Query for "How many users submitted content each month"

Tags: mysql

I want to get a statistic of how many users submitted content each month for the last 4 months. I was thinking of a MySQL `UNION` but don't think that will work, cause it will probably show duplicate rows, cause AFAIK `UNION` only appends 2 query result sets.

My table structure is like this (a typically `node` table from Drupal -- for Drupal gurus):

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| nid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| vid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | UNI | 0       |                |
| type      | varchar(32)      | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| language  | varchar(12)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| title     | varchar(255)     | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| uid       | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| status    | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 1       |                |
| created   | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| changed   | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| comment   | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| promote   | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| sticky    | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| tnid      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| translate | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And the column which holds the time a node was submitted is `created`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like that (doesn't seem that elegant...)

```
select count(distinct(t1.uid)) from node t1
inner join node t2 on t2.uid = t1.uid and t2.created between date_add(now(), interval -2 month) and date_add(now(), interval -1 month)
inner join node t3 on t3.uid = t1.uid and t3.created between date_add(now(), interval -3 month) and date_add(now(), interval -2 month)
inner join node t4 on t4.uid = t1.uid and t4.created between date_add(now(), interval -4 month) and date_add(now(), interval -3 month)
where t1.created between date_add(now(), interval -1 month) and now()
```

Comment: Had to make minor modifications to this, but it works. Took 6 minutes to complete and nearly killed the server :) But thanks, it's just what I wanted.

Comment: sorry for the "nearly-murder" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
select extract(MONTH from create), count(distinct uid)
from node
where create >= DATE_ADD(month,-4,CURDATE())
group by extract(MONTH from create)
```

I haven't tested it...

Comment: I've corrected the query and run it and it brings back some weird stuff... Doesn't this return the number of users that submitted content in ANY of the last 4 months rather than EACH of the last 4 months?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question: I thought you wanted a statistic for each month, rather than a count of users who have contributed in _every_ one of the last 4 months...

Comment: I had assumed you were looking for (a statistic of how many (users submitted content each month) for the last 4 months). If you want (a statistic of how many (users submitted content each month for the last 4 months)), then @Raphaël's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10412578/98806) looks better :)

Comment: Yes now you understood me, sorry for being unclear. Tried @Raphael's answer and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTH(create) as Month,
        (SELECT COUNT(vid) FROM Table WHERE MONTH(create) = Month)
FROM Table
ORDER BY Month DECS
LIMIT 4
```